# Why does File History say no usable drives found?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

When I try to select a volume as a backup destination for [File History](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-history-in-windows-5de0e203-ebae-05ab-db85-d5aa0a199255) I get the message "no usable drives found".

1. I plug in a hard drive via USB that's previously been used to backup to (via SMB) using File History in Windows 10.
2. The NTFS volume on the drive doesn't auto mount, so I assign it a drive letter manually.
3. File History refuses to acknowledge the presence of the volume despite it being browsable and writable by my (admin) account. No permission changes make any difference.

What's going on? How is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether Windows' partition manager says the drive is MBR.

Apparently File History will choke on either MBR drives, or on Hybrid MBR drives, or, alternatively, one or both of those are non-eligible for auto mounting for some reason and non-auto mounted volumes are excluded from being backup destination candidates for some reason. It's unclear to me which it is.

A search for "file history MBR GPT" in order to confirm this yields no relevant results.

1. Confirm whether it's a hybrid MBR drive by using `gdisk` in e.g. Ubuntu. As I recall `gdisk` is also available for Windows.
2. If it is, use `gdisk` to write a new protective MBR to the drive.
3. Confirm that Windows now auto mounts the volumes.
4. The volumes should be selectable as backup targets.